# How to get the content of a tweet using web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, cheerio

I have tried using puppeteer however I would try to get the information by passing in the x-path and it would never return any information. The exact same program worked with a different site but not twitter. Is there a way to get the contents of a tweet using cheerio or some other method? I have access to the twitter API however the documentation is difficult to understand.

EDIT CODE: Here is my code for pupputeer it for some reason gets hung up at the await page.waitfornavigation() only for twitter. for any other website this works.

```
const Apify = require('apify');
 
var OldAlphaAIData = {TICKER:"", REF:"", SIGNAL:""} 
Apify.main(async () => {
    const input = await Apify.getValue('INPUT');
 
    const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/MarketsTicker');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    do
    {
        console.log('ffff');
        var timenow = new Date(); //Get Date
        timenow.setHours(timenow.getHours() + 1);
        var AlphaAIData = {TICKER:"", REF:"", SIGNAL:""};
        var everything;
        var everythingarray = [];
 
        //xpath to 1st twitter message      
        const [el0] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[1]');    
        const txt0 = await el0.getProperty('textContent');
        everything = await txt0.jsonValue();
        console.log(everything);
    }while(true);
});
```

Comment: Hello @ItIsN3RD and welcome to StackOverflow. Would you happen to have any excerpts from your code  that you can share and an example of what you are trying to crape out of twitter? In any case the API would be the go to solution except if your needs are not covered by it. Can you provide a more detailed description of what it is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey @Arch Thanks for helping! I updated my post. Like i said above pupputeer gets hungup at the waitfornavigation and nothing fires off inside the dowhile loop for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what it is that you are trying to extract from each tweet and how you approach the problem but the documentation of the [twitter module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) is quite straightforward, assuming you are working with node based on your question's tags.

```js
var Twitter = require('twitter');
 
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});
 
var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs'};
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
  }
});
```

Of course for this to work you would need to register for access to the API of and provide these details using the appropriate variables such as consumer_key, consumer_secret etc.

---

UPDATE: I've managed to get your code working for twitter, please have a look at the following changes, the most important being the `await page.waitForXPath(xpath);`, which waits for the xpath to load first before attempting to fetch its contents. Also the xpath was different, I've pointed further inside the DOM to the span that holds the message.

```js
const Apify = require('apify');

var OldAlphaAIData = { TICKER: "", REF: "", SIGNAL: "" }
Apify.main(async () => {
    const input = await Apify.getValue('INPUT');

    const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/MarketsTicker')
    await navigationPromise

    console.log('ffff');
    var timenow = new Date(); //Get Date
    timenow.setHours(timenow.getHours() + 1);
    var AlphaAIData = { TICKER: "", REF: "", SIGNAL: "" };
    var everything;
    var everythingarray = [];

    //xpath to 1st twitter message      
    const xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span';
    await page.waitForXPath(xpath);
    const [el0] = await page.$x(xpath);
    const txt0 = await el0.getProperty('textContent');
    everything = await txt0.jsonValue();
    console.log(everything);

});
```

For simplicity I removed the infinite while loop as it was printing the first tweet indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response time. So that code snippet worked and i was able to get the first tweet by doing console.log(tweets[0]); however how would i extract the message content from that.

Comment: Have you tried tweets[0].text? You can have a look at the documentation for further details https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/tree/master/examples#streams

Comment: Hi @ItIsN3RD, has any of the proposed solutions (including the update) worked for you? If they did, can you mark any correct answers as so?